# Use.js to set the height of highcharter plot and shinydashboard box

Tags: r, highcharts, shinydashboard

I have a shiny app in which I try to set the the height of the `highcharter` plot and the `box` that includes it with the same .js code. But it does not seem to respond.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(highcharter)

jscode <-
  '$(document).on("shiny:connected", function(e) {
      var jsHeight = 0.65 * document.body.clientWidth; 
      Shiny.onInputChange("GetScreenHeight", jsHeight);
  });
'

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPagePlus(
    header = dashboardHeaderPlus(
    ),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),

    body = dashboardBody(
      tags$script(jscode),
      boxPlus(
        title = "Closable Box with dropdown", 
        closable = TRUE, 
        width = NULL,
        status = "warning", 
        solidHeader = FALSE, 
        collapsible = TRUE,
        highchartOutput("pl",height = "100%")
      )
    )

  ),
  server = function(input, output) {

    output$pl <- renderHighchart({
      data(diamonds, mpg, package = "ggplot2")

      hchart(mpg, "scatter", hcaes(x = displ, y = hwy, group = class))%>%
        hc_size(height =input$GetScreenHeight )
    })
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a workaround using `renderUI`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(highcharter)

jscode <- '$(document).on("shiny:connected", function(e) {
           var jsHeight = 0.65 * document.body.clientWidth;
           Shiny.onInputChange("GetScreenHeight", jsHeight);
           });'

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPagePlus(
    header = dashboardHeaderPlus(),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
    body = dashboardBody(
      tags$script(jscode),
      boxPlus(
        title = "Closable Box with dropdown",
        closable = TRUE,
        width = NULL,
        status = "warning",
        solidHeader = FALSE,
        collapsible = TRUE,
        uiOutput("plUI")
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {

    output$pl <- renderHighchart({
      data(diamonds, mpg, package = "ggplot2")
      hchart(mpg, "scatter", hcaes(x = displ, y = hwy, group = class))
    })

    output$plUI <- renderUI({highchartOutput("pl", height = input$GetScreenHeight)})
  }
)
```

Another very simple possibility to get relative plot heights is using the [css unit 'vh'](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp). Try e.g. `highchartOutput("pl", height = "80vh")` in your initial version (without `renderUI`). However, this way the plot is resized with the browser window.

Comment: thank you I have created a similar quesion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59316825/use-js-to-set-bot-height-and-width-of-highcharter-plot